# calling ramda compose in nodejs class

Tags: node.js, class, mocha.js, sinon, ramda.js

I have the following method `skipLoggingThisRequest` in a `node js` class which I am trying to test. The method is supposed to return either `true` or `false`, based on the path in request, using `ramda compose` to get to that value. However in my tests, no matter what path I set in the request object, my `skipLoggingThisRequest` always returns true.

What am I missing here?

my class:

```
import { compose, filter, join, toPairs, map, prop, flip, contains, test, append } from 'ramda'
import { create, env } from 'sanctuary'
import { isEmpty, flattenDeep } from 'lodash'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import log from 'menna'

class MyClass {

    constructor (headerList) {
        this.headerWhiteList = flattenDeep(append(headerList, []));
    }

    static getBody (req) {
        return (!isEmpty(req.body) ? JSON.stringify(req.body) : '');
    }

    static S () {
        return create({ checkTypes: false, env });
    }

    static isInList () {
        return flip(contains);
    }

    static isInWhitelist () {
        return compose(this.isInList(this.headerWhiteList), this.S.maybeToNullable, this.S.head);
    }

    static parseHeaders () {
        return (req) => compose(join(','), map(join(':')), filter(this.isInWhitelist), toPairs, prop('headers'));
    }

    skipLoggingThisRequest () {
        return (req) => compose(test(/^.*(swagger|docs|health).*$/), prop('path'))
    }

    logger (req, res, next) {
        if (this.skipLoggingThisRequest(req)) {
            console.log('Skipping')
            return next();
        }

        const primaryText = chalk.inverse(`${req.ip} ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`);
        const secondaryText = chalk.gray(`${this.parseHeaders(req)} ${this.getBody(req)}`);
        log.info(`${primaryText} ${secondaryText}`);

        return next();
    }
}

export default MyClass
```

My tests:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import MyClass from '../lib/MyClass';

describe('MyClass', () => {
    const headerList = ['request-header-1', 'request-header-2'];

    const request = {
        'headers': {
            'request-header-1': 'yabadaba',
            'request-header-2': 'dooooooo'
        },
        'ip': 'shalalam',
        'method': 'GET',
        'originalUrl': 'http://myOriginalUrl.com',
        'body': ''
    };
    const response = {};

    const nextStub = sinon.stub();

    describe('Logs request', () => {
        const myInstance = new MyClass(headerList);
        const skipLogSpy = sinon.spy(myInstance, 'skipLoggingThisRequest');
        request.path = '/my/special/path';
        myInstance.logger(request, response, nextStub);
        sinon.assert.called(nextStub);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.skipLoggingThisRequest(req)` returns a function (`(req) => compose(test(/^.*(swagger|docs|health).*$/), prop('path'))`).

It does not return a boolean. However, since functions are truthy, your `if` statement always executes.

What you most likely want to do is `this.skipLoggingThisRequest()(req)`. You get the function and then apply a request to it.

Demonstration of what's going on:

```js
const testFunction = () => (test) => test === "Hello!";
console.log(testFunction);
console.log(testFunction());
console.log(testFunction()("Hello!"));
console.log(testFunction()("Goodbye!"));

if (testFunction) {
  console.log("testFunction is truthy.");
}

if (testFunction()) {
  console.log("testFunction() is truthy.");
}

if (testFunction()("Hello!")) {
  console.log('testFunction()("Hello!") is truthy.');
}

if (!testFunction()("Goodbye!")) {
  console.log('testFunction()("Goodbye!") is falsey.');
}
```